# Производительность сайта

Tags: php, mysql

Есть сайт, файл индес пхп. Есть БД, там есть таблица контент, ну естественно там статьи. 
Если индекс пхп?=6, он показывает статью ид = 6 и тд. Ну есть еще 4-5 других страниц, типа о нас, напишите нам и т.д.
На данный момент количество статей около 400, но говорят, если будет более 1000 статей (ну много), то сайт будет "глючить".
Насколько это правда?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ерунда, скорость получения будет зависеть от характеристик сервера, если в таблице поле id стоит как PRIMARY KEY с типом smallint и длиной 5, то никаких проблем с получением не будет. В таком случае id может быть чуть больше 65000. Если хочется больше, то тип поля mediumint и длина 8, тогда до 16млн

Answer (score 1):

Это ложь. =)
1000 статей для MySQL даже на слабом хостинге простая задача даже если вовсю использовать полнотекстовый поиск.
Проблемы могут начаться, если на сайт придет толпа хомячков. Но там и визитка может рухнуть.

Comment: Что за хомячки?

Comment: Пользователи, в большом количестве))

Comment: Все верно, объем записей в БД никак не связан с количеством запросов.

Answer (score 0):

Помню еще давно когда начинал изучать php и sql тоже почему-то думал что от этого очень сильно зависит скорость работы... Ну вообщем страшным циклом for киданул в таблицу articles 2 миллиона записей, на скорости выборки практически не отразилось :)
PS:тем более у вас выборка по индуксу проходит, а я когда это делал тогда еще слабо понимал что это такое, ну вообщем небыло их там кроме primary id, а выборка производилась по title...

Answer (score 0):

1000 статей, если не дергать всё разом, если у сервера есть хотя бы 512ОЗУ проблем не будет, сделайте выборку по как уже говорилось ID и указывайте только необходимые строки, ну если совсем всё плохо, или проект расчитан на большую нагрузку.. можно как вариант проиндексировать основные затрагиваемые поля, для более быстрого получения доступа к ним( при индексации база станет занить чучуть больше места на харде)